# How to solve Ambiguous use of 'subscript' in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a swift file in the latest version of xcode 7.3 and I can compile and execute this in emulator, but then I select my iPhone device I get Ambiguous use of 'subscript' in prints like:

```
  print("Json COmpleto\(jsonCompleto.valueForKey("description")![2])")
```

And in other lines where I use a String...

[image]

I try add a parse to print line like: as! String, but this not solve my error.

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Cast your `jsonCompleto`or `jsonCompleto.valueForKey("description")` to your desired type e.g. `as! [String]` or just `as! NSArray`.

Comment: This work!. You can write this like answer. Thanks!