# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' on device

Tags: swift, device, ambiguous

I have my app finish on my emulator, but when I try to use on my phone, I had 2 bugs `Ambiguous use of 'subscript'`

I was reading this post, but can't fix it. [How to solve Ambiguous use of 'subscript' in Swift 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350245/how-to-solve-ambiguous-use-of-subscript-in-swift-2)

[image]

The problem is here

```
        let favs = rescataRegistrosFav()
        print(favs)
        print("-----------------------------------------------")



        if(arrayCompleta[row][2] == ""){
            cell.imagenMovil.image = nil
        }else{
            cell.imagenMovil.image = UIImage(named: "mov.png")
        }


        if(favs.count > 0){


            for i in 0...favs.count-1
            {
                for j in 0...favs[i].count-1
                {

                    print("MUESTRO.....\(favs[i][j] as! String)")   //Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

                    if(favs[i][j] as! String == cell.getNombreCelda()){  ////Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
                        cell.botonFav.setImage(UIImage(named: imagenFav[1])!, forState: .Normal)

                        return cell
                    }



                }
            }


        }
```

In my restacaRegistrosFavs I cast like other post, but nothing.

```
func rescataRegistrosFav() -> NSArray{

    //_____REPARARAQUI_______

    var array = [[String]]()

    if((NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("MIARRAYFAV")) != nil){
       return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("MIARRAYFAV")! as! [[String]]
    }

    return array
}
```

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSArray` is effectively an `Array<AnyObject>` so there are probably a few types that conform to `AnyObject` that also implement a subscript function. Instead of declaring `rescataRegistrosFav` as returning an `NSArray` try being more specific and declaring it like:

```
func rescataRegistrosFav() -> [[String]]
```